# Notepad ++ : How to Replace as the description

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

**I have lines like these**

```
abye/>abye
abys/>abys
aced/>aced
aces/>aces
```

**I want it like this**

```
abye
abys
aced
aces
```

Is it possible? If it is then please someone show me the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the replace dialog select the **Regular Expressions** option for the search mode.

Then in the replace find box enter: `.*/>`

And replace all

This will remove everything before and including the characters /> on each line.

Answer (score 0):

If the portion of lines you want to select always starts (in all lines), at the same position, you can simply use ["block select"/"Column mode editing"](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html) to achieve the same. To do so, use <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>arrow keys</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd> + `select using mouse`

[image: Notepad++ Column select]